# Free $\oplus$ non-free $\cong$ free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Can it happen that a direct sum of a free module and a non-free module is (isomorphic to) a free module?

Comment: Yes. Google for "stably free module" (e.g. on Keith Conrad's page).

Comment: Don't you need a torsion-free condition on the non-free side?

Comment: What is an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example from geometry. The module over $C^{\infty} (S^2)$ of tangent vector fields on the 2 sphere is not free (every vector field has a zero), but if you stabilize it by a free module of rank 1 ( you think of normal vector field to the sphere) you obtain a free rank 3 module : the restriction of vector fields on $R^3$ to the sphere.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/58035/121097